# IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6

Tags: python, python3

教科書通りのコードを入力しました．
`IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6`
のエラーが出てしまいます．
ご教授ください．

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X=np.arange(-1.0,1.0,0.2)
Y=np.arange(-1.0,1.0,0.2)

Z=np.zeros((10,10))

w_x=2.5
w_y=3.0

bias=0.1

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):

        u=X[i]*w_x + Y[j]*w_y + bias
        y=1/(1+np.exp(-u))
        Z[j][i]=y

plt.imshow(Z,"gray", vmin=0.0,vmax=1.0)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[np.arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)は等差数列を作成する関数です。

そのため`np.arange(start=-0.1,stop=1.0,step=0.2)`(startなど変数名は分かりやすくするため追記)は下記の6個しか値を返しません。

```
array([-0.1,  0.1,  0.3,  0.5,  0.7,  0.9])
```

なので`for i in range(10):`のコードでは`X[6]`以降にアクセスするため、表題のエラーが発生します。

以上が[編集前の質問(～Rev2)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/53823/revisions)への回答です。

---

最新の質問では下記のコードで正常に動作することを手元で確認しました。
`IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6`が発生する要素がないのですが、編集後の内容でエラー内容が変わった場合は、質問を再度編集してエラー内容を追記なさってください。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.arange(-1.0,1.0,0.2)
Y = np.arange(-1.0,1.0,0.2)
Z = np.zeros((10,10))
w_x=2.5
w_y=3.0
bias=0.1

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        u=X[i]*w_x + Y[j]*w_y + bias
        y = 1/(1+np.exp(-u))
        Z[j][i]=y

plt.imshow(Z,"gray", vmin=0.0,vmax=1.0)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```